# Find the min, max value in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, graphics

```
alist = [(1,3),(2,5),(2,4),(7,5)]
```

I need to get the min max value for each position in tuple.

Fox example: 
The exepected output of alist is

```
min_x = 1
max_x = 7

min_y = 3
max_y = 5
```

Is there any easy way to do?

Comment: How many times do you want to iterate the list? (4 times, 2 times or 1 times).

Answer (score 64):

```
map(max, zip(*alist))
```

This first unzips your list, then finds the max for each tuple position

```
>>> alist = [(1,3),(2,5),(2,4),(7,5)]
>>> zip(*alist)
[(1, 2, 2, 7), (3, 5, 4, 5)]
>>> map(max, zip(*alist))
[7, 5]
>>> map(min, zip(*alist))
[1, 3]
```

This will also work for tuples of any length in a list.

Comment: can you say a bit more about what the * in front of alist does?  zip behaves REALLY differently without the * there...

Comment: @Andrew Sure, the `*` splice the list into the arguments of the function. The best way to understand this is by example: `f(*[1, 2, 3])` is exactly the same as `f(1, 2, 3)`, so `zip(*[(1, 3), (2, 5), (2, 4), (7, 5)])` is the same as `zip((1, 3), (2, 5), (2, 4), (7, 5))` which returns `[(1, 2, 2, 7), (3, 5, 4, 5)]`. For complete, gory details see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls)

Comment: Speaking of bloody details in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), see sure to see tiwo's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8303138/355230) -- which really should've been posted as a comment here -- about not needing the `zip` calls and just using `map(max, *alist)` and `map(min, *alist)`.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> alist = [(1,3),(2,5),(2,4),(7,5)]
>>> min(alist)[0], max(alist)[0]
(1, 7)
>>> min(alist, key=itemgetter(1))[1], max(alist, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
(3, 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `zip` is not necessary, so this simplifies to `map(max, *data)` (where `data` is an iterator over tuples or lists of the same length).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, because `map(max, *alist)` is `[7, 6]` (as is `map(max, *iter(alist))`).

Comment: @martineau `map(max, *alist)` returns `[7, 5]`, just like `map(max, zip(*alist))` does.

Comment: @flornquake: Actually both of them result in `[7, 6]` in Python 2.7. My initial comment was because there's nothing in the original question about using `zip`, so I don't understand the relevance of this "answer". Perhaps it was a comment about @cobbal's answer. It does not apply to mine however which uses `map(sorted, zip(*alist))`.

Comment: @martineau it's actually `[7, 5]`. In the context of the question, it's the best answer.

Comment: @Grief: Using Python 2.7.12, I just ran `alist = [(1,6), (2,5), (2,4), (7,5)]` followed by `map(max, *alist)` (and `map(max, *iter(alist))`) and the result is `[7, 6]`.

Comment: @martineau great! This is the correct answer, right? You used your own `alist`, not OP's one, that is why the result is different

Comment: @Grief: Indeed, I used the `alist` from my answer rather than the one in the OP's question (and erred assuming they were the same). Regardless, even if the finding the min or max is faster than sorting to get them both at once, that's not the only consideration when writing software. The OP specifically asked for an easy way to do it for a list of tuples (not just of a certain size). IMO scaling the approach in this answer up to do mins _and_ maxes beyond tuples of two is more awkward than just using the more general approach in my answer which can handle tuples of any size equally well.

Answer (score 3):

A generalized approach would be something like this:

```
alist = [(1,6),(2,5),(2,4),(7,5)]

temp = map(sorted, zip(*alist))
min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y = temp[0][0], temp[0][-1], temp[1][0], temp[1][-1]
```

For Python 3, you'd need change the line that creates`temp`to:

```
temp = tuple(map(sorted, zip(*alist)))
```

The idea can be abstracted into a function which works in both Python 2 and 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
try:
    from functools import reduce  # moved into functools in release 2.6
except ImportError:
    pass

# readable version
def minmaxes(seq):
    pairs = tuple()
    for s in map(sorted, zip(*seq)):
        pairs += (s[0], s[-1])
    return pairs

# functional version
def minmaxes(seq):
    return reduce(tuple.__add__, ((s[0], s[-1]) for s in map(sorted, zip(*seq))))

alist = [(1,6), (2,5), (2,4), (7,5)]
min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y = minmaxes(alist)
print(' '.join(['{},{}']*2).format(*minmaxes(alist)))  # 1,7 4,6

triplets = [(1,6,6), (2,5,3), (2,4,9), (7,5,6)]
min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, min_z, max_z = minmaxes(triplets)
print(' '.join(['{},{}']*3).format(*minmaxes(triplets)))  # 1,7 4,6 3,9
```

Comment: This is bad solution since sorting is `O(n×log(n))` while finding minimum is `O(n)`

Comment: @Grief: To paraphrase a popular American idiom, generality isn't free.

Comment: @cobbal answer improved by @tiwo is not less general but much more straightforward: `list(map(max, *[(1,9),(2,8),(3,7)]))` returns `[3, 9]` as well as `min`-version would return `[1, 7]`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using enumerate and list comprehension

```
alist = [(1,3),(2,5),(2,4),(7,5)]

for num, k in enumerate(['X', 'Y']):
    print 'max_%s' %k, max([i[num] for i in alist])
    print 'min_%s' %k, min([i[num] for i in alist])
```

Answer (score 0):

For python 3:

```
alist = [(1,3),(2,5),(2,4),(7,5)]    
[x_range, y_range] = list(zip(map(min, *test_list), map(max, *alist)))

print(x_range, y_range) #prints: (1, 7) (3, 5)
```

Since zip/map returns an iterator `<object at 0x00>` you need to use `list()`