# Python: how to get the edge values from this list

Tags: python, list

I've got a python list like

```
a = [
    [[1,2,(3,4)],[1,2,(5)],[-3,3,(3)],[8,-2,(5)]],
    [[1,2,(3,4,5)],[-1,222,(3,4,5)],[99,2,(3)],[8,-2,(4,5)]]
]
```

The tuple in each list element is total useless, please ignore that but delete them

I want to get the max min value from each list element in each position

The exepected output structure is

```
li = [[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] ]
```

In this case li is `[[-3, -2, 8, 3], [-1, -2,99, 222]]`

So is there any easy to do ?Thank

Comment: Seems like almost the same question you asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002796/python-find-the-min-max-value-in-a-list

And if you want a tuple with a single element, the proper syntax is `(x,)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a minor stylistic point, you should use tuples for small fix-length lists. I.e.: use `(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)` instead of `[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]`.

```
[(min(t[0] for t in lst),
  min(t[1] for t in lst),
  max(t[0] for t in lst),
  max(t[1] for t in lst))
 for lst in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to numpy, you can use [`numpy.amax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html?highlight=max#numpy.amax). You can use the `axis` parameter to get the maximum of a certain column of the array.

Comment: Could we not including other libraries?

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip:

```
a = [ [[1,2,(3,4)],[1,2,(5)],[-3,3,(3)],[8,-2,(5)] ],
[[1,2,(3,4,5)],[-1,222,(3,4,5)],[99,2,(3)],[8,-2,(4,5)] ] ]

>>> i, h = zip(*a[0]), zip(*a[1])
>>> [min(i[0]), min(i[1]), max(i[0]), max(i[1])]
[-3, -2, 8, 3]
>>> [min(h[0]), min(h[1]), max(h[0]), max(h[1])]
[-1, -2, 99, 222]
```

Comment: Could we use loop? since I may got more elements in a list than that?

Comment: But if the list structure is the same you can use the same method.

Comment: Use a list comprehension for larger inputs: `[[min(i[0]), min(i[1]), max(i[0]), max(i[1])] for i in (zip(*i) for i in a)]`.