# Calculating the min, max, and average of a list's contents in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, statistics

So, the problem that I am working on is "Write, debug, and test a program to calculate and print the minimum, maximum, and average of a list of positive test scores. Prompt the user for how many scores are to be entered.  Expect each score will be entered one per line. Provide a prompt for each score."

So this what I currently have, but I'm stuck at finding the min, max, and avg.

```
def scores():
    print('we are starting')
    count = int(input('Enter amount of scores: '))
    print('Each will be entered one per line')
    scoreList = []
    for i in range(1, count+1):
            scoreList.append(int(input('Enter score: ')))
            print(scoreList)
    print(scoreList)
    print('thank you the results are:')
    mysum = sum(count)
    # mysum needs to be a float
    average = 1.0*mysum / n
    print ('Total: ', str(count))
    print ('Average: ', str(average))
    print ('Minimum: ', str(min(count)))
    print ('Maximum: ', str(max(count))) 
scores()
```

I'm not sure if it would be easier to do an elif type statement as I said I'm really new to this and I'm still just trying to understand what's going on in this code.

Next, I need to "expand the program to generate a score by grade table. For each rank of grade [A,B,C,D,F] the program counts the number of grades in the rank. The program prints a table of count by rank and provides the percentage of total grades in each rank."

The ranks are as follows:

```
A = 91 - 100   
B = 81 - 90   
C = 71 - 80   
D = 61 - 70    
F =  0 - 60
```

I would just appreciate some assistance or some input on this.

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere? What is `n`?

Comment: @jeffpc1993 It is generally ok to ask homework questions as long as they are valid questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Find the min, max value in a list of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002796/python-find-the-min-max-value-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not realize jeffpc1993. I agree and you are entirely right. but @Selcuk - "n" was originally what "scores" was refereed as but I changed it thinking scores was more descriptive for myself and forgot to replace that variable.  I'm resorting to asking here as I feel as though I have no more options for myself and to be honest I've been doing allnighters all week with midterms and work so this is my last resort honestly and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @JennGaudio That's ok, I wasn't implying that you are doing something wrong. Just wanted to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not far off, your main problem seems to be in confusing your variables, so that you make references to the wrong thing at the wrong time.

For example, instead of looking for a `min` and `max` of `count` (which is a single integer value), you want to look for `min` and `max` of `scoreList` (which is a list, and therefore iterable with the `min` and `max` methods).

Same issue for `sum`. The corrected bits of the code would be:

```
mysum = sum(scoreList)
# mysum needs to be a float
average = 1.0*mysum / count
print ('Total: ', str(mysum))
print ('Average: ', str(average))
print ('Minimum: ', str(min(scoreList)))
print ('Maximum: ', str(max(scoreList)))
```

As for working with the grade chart, that's a separate question, and would be better served by posting as separate, along with some code to show what you've tried. But yes, `elif` statements are a valid way to go with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most pythonic way I could come up with, of course the math module has all of these lol!

```
def min(data):
    '''return min of itterable data
        '''
    minimum = data[0]
    for i in data:
        if i < minimum:
            minimum = i
    return minimum

def max(data):
    '''return max of itterable data
        '''
    maximum = data[0]
    for i in data:
        if i > maximum:
            maximum = i
    return maximum

def avg(data):
    '''
        return average of itterable data
    '''
    return sum(data)/len(data)

data = [1,2,1,3,6,4,5]
print (min(data), max(data), avg(data))
```