# Min and Max of each index in sublists

Tags: python

Need to get the min and max values of each index in the sublists of a list.

If my list is `[[1, 2], [4, 1], [2, 2], [1, 6], [5, 3]]`, I do the following:

```
xmin = min(i[0] for i in mylist)
ymin = min(i[1] for i in mylist)
xmax = max(i[0] for i in mylist)
ymax = max(i[1] for i in mylist)
# Results:
xmin = 1
xmax = 5
ymin = 1
ymax = 6
```

While very explicit in what I am doing with those 4 lines, is there a way to get it in tuple unpack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Find the min, max value in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002796/python-find-the-min-max-value-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: @Kevin Pretty similar. Cant delete now, too many answers.

Comment: tbh I think this should be closed - it's basically the same qu. even happy to delete my answer if it is closed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for list of lists `p`, we can transpose and unpack using

```
p1, p2 = zip(*p)
```

then find min and max as

```
max(p1)
min(p1)
max(p2)
min(p2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a generic solution, you should not dynamically name variables. Instead, you can use a dictionary. This will work for any list of lists where each sublist is of the same length.

```
L = [[1, 2], [4, 1], [2, 2], [1, 6], [5, 3]]

from operator import itemgetter

n = len(L[0])

d_min = {i: min(map(itemgetter(i), L)) for i in range(n)}
d_max = {i: max(map(itemgetter(i), L)) for i in range(n)}

print(d_min, d_max, sep='\n')

{0: 1, 1: 1}
{0: 5, 1: 6}
```

Comment: Why do you feel I am dynamically naming variables?

Comment: `l1, l2 = list(zip(*l))`. Explicit / dynamic, equally bad practice IMO :). If 1 is an index, make it a dictionary key!

Comment: Explicit is always better than implicit, not sure why you feel that way.

Comment: So for 4 columns, you would have `l1, l2, l3, l4 = list(zip(*l))`. That's a lot of typing :). Let's hope you don't have 100 columns.

Comment: I think @jpp solution falls under **beautiful is better than ugly** over it's "apparent lack of explicit"

Comment: No, I'm not making the program flexible to handle cases it shouldn't deal with. `if cols > 2: return`. I see your point, however this script is for a specific case, as shown in the OP.

Comment: @jpp I agree in come cases, however the OP asked for tuple unpacking, and might have an explicit reason, e.g. `heights, weights = zip(*l)`

Comment: While tuple packing may be sufficient for OP, there are many cases where the problem as stated is an XY problem and dictionaries are the way to go. I'm catering for that audience.